# asynchronous loading content in windows mobile 6.5 in c#

Tags: windows-mobile

hey guys i am downloading data from url by make http request and then displaying data on mobile but as data is huge it takes lot of time to load the page so do you have solution for it or you know how to asynchronous loading content in windows mobile 6.5 in c# with example if any.........................

Comment: This question is too generic to be answered. You should provide more details and possibly some code. How do you download the data? What do you mean by "display"? What kind of "data" is this? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Download the data on a background thread.  When downloading is complete either use an event to notify the UI that the data is ready or call a method that updates the UI (via Control.Invoke).

Comment: Hey friends i have got the trick to load data async i wrote the event on forms activated event and use background thread hope this might be help fully to u all..............